# CORS on Webjars in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors, webjars

I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.0.M2 and Spring 4.3.0.RC1, trying to enable CORS support in a simple app. I have this added:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer webMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**");
        }
    };
}
```

I also have webjars pulled in through Gradle, such as:

```
compile('org.webjars:jquery:2.2.3')
```

The CORS support works fine with my REST API (via `@RestController`), but somehow it doesn't seem to work when accessing my webjars. For example (UPDATE: less confusing example), requesting:

```
http://example.org/webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.0/package.json
```

gets a response with the correct content but lacking the expected CORS headers, which of course defeats any actual CORS request. I can't figure out why that would be an exception to the `/**` mapping. How do I fix it?

Comment: CORS only applies to certain AJAX requests.

Comment: Understood, but the question is about configuring the server. Any number of static files in the webjar, in particular JSON files, might be useful to load through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't need cors configuration . In other words, you can access JavaScript resources from a site which doesn't enable cors.

From [wiki site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), we can obvious know that a website can freely embed images, stylesheets, scripts, iframes, videos and some plugin content (such as Adobe Flash) from any other domain. So even if you are enabling CORS on your website, but your resource is `javascript`, so the request does not add CORS header.

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet copied from documentation is just a sample of showing how to enable CROS in a quick way. This code snippet is not complete. Using this will mess up what WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter provided for you.